# Tensorflow: How do I give a network 2 separate vectors as input?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to implement a network similar to the one mentioned in this paper http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~wolf/papers/deepchess.pdf, wherein the network recieves two separate vectors as input and has to output either 1,0 or 0,1.

I'm not sure how to implement it, for example taking a simple case: I want to run each vector through a basic nueral network that will output a new vector, doing this twice will result in 2 vectors, concatenate those two vectors and run it through another network.

Practically I'm not sure how to do this, and I can't seem to find examples of anything similar...

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way might be to create two NN that has weights shared, and feed the two vectors in simultaneously. Lookup variables sharing for details.